# Automatically populate GravityForms field with rotating values

Tags: wordpress, forms, rotation, gravity, auto-populate

I'm using gravity forms to send sales inquiries to a CRM.

We have 3 salespeople who each need to receive inquiries in a rotation.

For example:

- Entry 1 - Tom
- Entry 2 - Richard
- Entry 3 - Harry
- Entry 4 - Tom
- Entry 5 - Richard
- Entry 6 - Harry

Each time there's a new entry on the contact form I need to include a hidden field containing the name of the next sales person in the rotation to pass to our CRM.

I have some experience in PHP but not familiar with Gravity. Hopefully, someone can point me in the right direction to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to accomplish this:

```
/**
 * Gravity Wiz // Gravity Forms // Rotating Values
 * http://gravitywiz.com/
 */
add_filter( 'gform_entry_post_save', function( $entry ) {

    // Specify an array of values that will be rotated through.
    $rotation = array( 'Tom', 'Richard', 'Harry' );

    // Specify the form ID for which this functioanlity applies.
    $form_id = 1722;

    // Specify the field ID in which the current rotation value will be saved.
    $field_id = 1;

    /* DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE */

    // Bail out of this is not our designated form.
    if( $entry['form_id'] != $form_id ) {
        return $entry;
    }

    // Get the last submitted entry.
    $last_entry = rgar( GFAPI::get_entries( $entry['form_id'], array( 'status' => 'active' ), array( 'direction' => 'desc' ), array( 'offset' => 1, 'page_size' => 1 ) ), 0 );

    // Get the value submitted for our designated field in the last entry.
    $last_value = rgar( $last_entry, $field_id );

    // Determine the next index at which to fetch our value.
    $next_index = empty( $last_value ) ? 0 : array_search( $last_value, $rotation ) + 1;
    if( $next_index > count( $rotation ) - 1 ) {
        $next_index = 0;
    }

    // Get the next value based on our rotation.
    $next_value = $rotation[ $next_index ];

    // Update the value of our designated field in the database.
    GFAPI::update_entry_field( $entry['id'], $field_id, $next_value );

    // Update the value of our designated field in the $entry object that will be used to continuing processing the current submission.
    $entry[ $field_id ] = $next_value;

    return $entry;
} );
```

Also available as a gist for posterity: https://gist.github.com/spivurno/8908a589aa6ceaf6ff0a874324bfbf93